# No longer possible to add multiple duplicate targets?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I happened upon [Novel with humans travelling to a distant planet becoming super-intelligent](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59506/novel-with-humans-travelling-to-a-distant-planet-becoming-super-intelligent), which is at one end of a small duplicate chain. I was going to simply edit [the ultimate parent in](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2697/story-featuring-smart-people-sent-on-a-space-mission-to-nowhere), so as to avoid having to reopen, then close, but that option doesn't seem to be present. Is this because it's an older question? Or was the ability to set multiple duplicate targets removed?

[image: Image of the screen with the duplicate prompt]

Sorry for the lack of hand-drawn arrows. Choosing to edit the question just lets me edit the text and tags.

Comment: There might be a separate question on whether the dupe targets ought to be modified in general, as that ultimate parent is very terse and doesn't really answer other parts of the linked questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Editing the duplicate list is only a [mod or gold badge holder privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links). That question doesn’t have the [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) tag which it needs, both because it should have the tag and so you can edit the list.

Comment: Ah, good catch! Fixed.